# Calculate dates and return a 0 if it is the current date or date passed in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, date-time

I need to calculate days between today and the 'Last day to offer' and have Excel return a `0` if today is the last day to offer or if the date has passed; otherwise it should return the number of days left to offer (taking into account weekends and holidays).

I currently have

```
=NETWORKDAYS(TODAY(),E20,Holiday)
```

as the formula to calculate the 'Days left to offer', but this (obviously) does not return a zero when appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use an `IF`?

```
=IF(NETWORKDAYS(TODAY(),E20,Holiday)<=1, 0, NETWORKDAYS(TODAY(),E20,Holiday))
```

Comment: I must have typed something wrong when I attempted that formula, because yours worked but mine didn't LOL. Thank you!

Comment: @Donna Haha, that happens to the best of us :) You're welcome!

Comment: Stupid parenthesis!! LOL